# Neural Network appears to be slow

Tags: performance, ai, julia, neural-network

I have some neural network Julia code which I'm hoping to speed up.  It's possibly simply poorly-designed, but I'm not convinced.

```
# This is line 1 (for the purpose of matching the profiler output's line numbers)

sigmoid(z::Float64) = 1/(1 + exp(-z))
sigmoidPrime(z::Float64) = sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))

### Types ###

abstract AbstractNode

type Edge
    source::AbstractNode
    target::AbstractNode
    weight::Float64
    derivative::Float64
    augmented::Bool

    Edge(source::AbstractNode, target::AbstractNode) = new(source, target, randn(), 0.0, false)
end

type Node <: AbstractNode
    incomingEdges::Vector{Edge}
    outgoingEdges::Vector{Edge}
    activation::Float64
    activationPrime::Float64

    Node() = new([], [], -1.0, -1.0)
end

type InputNode <: AbstractNode
    index::Int
    incomingEdges::Vector{Edge}
    outgoingEdges::Vector{Edge}
    activation::Float64

    InputNode(index::Int) = new(index, [], [], -1.0)
end

type BiasNode <: AbstractNode
    incomingEdges::Vector{Edge}
    outgoingEdges::Vector{Edge}
    activation::Float64

    BiasNode() = new([], [], 1.0)
end

type Network
    inputNodes::Vector{InputNode}
    hiddenNodes::Vector{Node}
    outputNodes::Vector{Node}

    function Network(layerSizes::Array, bias::Bool=true)
        inputNodes = [InputNode(i) for i in 1:layerSizes[1]];
        hiddenNodes = [Node() for _ in 1:layerSizes[2]];
        outputNodes = [Node() for _ in 1:layerSizes[3]];

        for inputNode in inputNodes
            for node in hiddenNodes
                edge = Edge(inputNode, node);
                push!(inputNode.outgoingEdges, edge)
                push!(node.incomingEdges, edge)
            end
        end

        for node in hiddenNodes
            for outputNode in outputNodes
                edge = Edge(node, outputNode);
                push!(node.outgoingEdges, edge)
                push!(outputNode.incomingEdges, edge)
            end
        end

        if bias == true
            biasNode = BiasNode()
            for node in hiddenNodes
                edge = Edge(biasNode, node);
                push!(biasNode.outgoingEdges, edge)
                push!(node.incomingEdges, edge)
            end
        end

        new(inputNodes, hiddenNodes, outputNodes)
    end
end


### Methods ###

function evaluate(obj::Node, inputVector::Array)
    if obj.activation > -0.5
        return obj.activation
    else
        weightedSum = sum([d.weight * evaluate(d.source, inputVector) for d in obj.incomingEdges])
        obj.activation = sigmoid(weightedSum)
        obj.activationPrime = sigmoidPrime(weightedSum)

        return obj.activation
    end
end

function evaluate(obj::InputNode, inputVector::Array)
    obj.activation = inputVector[obj.index]
    return obj.activation
end

function evaluate(obj::BiasNode, inputVector::Array)
    obj.activation = 1.0
    return obj.activation
end

function updateWeights(obj::AbstractNode, learningRate::Float64)
    for d in obj.incomingEdges
        if d.augmented == false
            d.augmented = true
            d.weight -= learningRate * d.derivative
            updateWeights(d.source, learningRate)
            d.derivative = 0.0
        end
    end
end

function compute(obj::Network, inputVector::Array)
    output = [evaluate(node, inputVector) for node in obj.outputNodes]
    for node in obj.outputNodes
        clear(node)
    end
    return output
end

function clear(obj::AbstractNode)
    for d in obj.incomingEdges
        obj.activation = -1.0
        obj.activationPrime = -1.0
        if d.augmented == true
            d.augmented = false
            clear(d.source)
        end
    end
end

function propagateDerivatives(obj::AbstractNode, error::Float64)
    for d in obj.incomingEdges
        if d.augmented == false
            d.augmented = true
            d.derivative += error * obj.activationPrime * d.source.activation
            propagateDerivatives(d.source, error * d.weight * obj.activationPrime)
        end
    end
end

function backpropagation(obj::Network, example::Array)
    output = [evaluate(node, example[1]) for node in obj.outputNodes]
    error = output - example[2]
    for (node, err) in zip(obj.outputNodes, error)
        propagateDerivatives(node, err)
    end
end

function train(obj::Network, labeledExamples::Array, sampleSize::Int, learningRate::Float64=0.7, iterations::Int=10000)
    for _ in 1:iterations
        println(_)
        batch = labeledExamples[rand(1:length(labeledExamples), sampleSize)]
        for ex in batch
            backpropagation(obj, ex)

            for node in obj.outputNodes
                clear(node)
            end
        end

        for node in obj.outputNodes
            updateWeights(node, learningRate)
        end

        for node in obj.outputNodes
            clear(node)
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the relevant `Profile.print()` backtrack (total "time"=10993):

> ```
>       7643 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; backpropagation; line: 154
>        2    ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 141
>        9    ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 142
>        103  ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 144
>         7 .../lib/julia/sys.dylib; *; (unknown line)
>         3 .../lib/julia/sys.dylib; +; (unknown line)
>          1 .../lib/julia/sys.dylib; +; (unknown line)
>        7517 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 145
>         241  ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 141
>         1118 ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 142
>         1    ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 143
>         4784 ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 144
>          375 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; *; (unknown line)
>           13 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; *; (unknown line)
>          550 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; +; (unknown line)
>           15 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; +; (unknown line)
>          354 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; convert; (unknown line)
>         1352 ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 145
>          2   ...ib/julia/sys.dylib; typeinf_ext; (unknown line)
>           2 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; typeinf; (unknown line)
>            2 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; typeinf; (unknown line)
>             2 ...lib/julia/sys.dylib; inlining_pass; (unknown line)
>              2 ...ib/julia/sys.dylib; inlining_pass; (unknown line)
>               2 ...ib/julia/sys.dylib; inlining_pass; (unknown line)
>                2 ...b/julia/sys.dylib; inlineable; (unknown line)
>                 1 ...b/julia/sys.dylib; cell_1d; (unknown line)
>          277 ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 141
>          18  ...a/neuralnetwork.jl; propagateDerivatives; line: 145
>      1725 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; train; line: 166
>       3    ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 130
>       7    ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 133
>       1715 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 135
>        110 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 130
>        18  ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 131
>        7   ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 132
>        940 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 133
>        625 ...ia/neuralnetwork.jl; clear; line: 135
> ```

There isn't a way I know of to highlight particular lines of code, but in the profiler traceback, the three suspicious lines are 142, 144, and 133.  Together they make up over half the time spent on the code, and yet all three seem rather innocuous.

Line 142 corresponds to a simple if statement `if d.augmented == false` in the `propagateDerivatives` function.

Line 144 corresponds to the line `d.derivative += error * obj.activationPrime * d.source.activation` also in the `propagateDerivatives` function. (The code spends a whopping 4784 times as long on this line as it does on the line right before it, even though they are accessed the same number of times, that seems pretty fishy to me.)

Line 133 corresponds to the if statement `if d.augmented == true` in the `clear` function.

In the end, even if I'm able to double its speed, it still isn't hardly as fast as different neural network algorithms with a less elaborate class structure written in PyPy.  This algorithm, while elegant, probably simply stores too much stuff in memory to be terribly efficient, that's my guess anyway.

Here is the flat Profiler backtrack:

> ```
>  Count File                             Function                                           Line
>    403 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib *                                                    -1
>    574 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib +                                                    -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib _basemod                                             -1
>      2 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib _iisconst                                            -1
>     64 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib _methods                                             -1
>     30 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib abstract_call                                        -1
>     32 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib abstract_call_gf                                     -1
>     48 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib abstract_eval                                        -1
>     20 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib abstract_eval_arg                                    -1
>     46 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib abstract_eval_call                                   -1
>     27 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib abstract_interpret                                   -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib cell_1d                                              -1
>      2 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib contains_is1                                         -1
>    360 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib convert                                              -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib copy!                                                -1
>      6 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib disassociate_julia_struct                            -1
>     18 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib effect_free                                          -1
>      2 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib eval_annotate                                        -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib getindex                                             -1
>  10932 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib include                                              -1
>  10932 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib include_from_node1                                   -1
>      2 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib inline_worthy                                        -1
>     18 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib inlineable                                           -1
>     62 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib inlining_pass                                        -1
>      8 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib is_known_call                                        -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib is_known_call_p                                      -1
>      2 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib isconst                                              -1
>      5 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib isconstantfunc                                       -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib length                                               -1
>      7 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib occurs_more                                          -1
>     24 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib occurs_outside_tupleref                              -1
>      4 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib stchanged                                            -1
>      2 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib stupdate                                             -1
>      3 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib tuple_elim_pass                                      -1
>     18 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib tupleref_elim_pass                                   -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib type_annotate                                        -1
>    146 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib typeinf                                              -1
>     47 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib typeinf_ext                                          -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib unique_name                                          -1
>      1 ...ces/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib unsafe_copy!                                         -1
>   1344 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl backpropagation                                     151
>      8 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl backpropagation                                     152
>      9 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl backpropagation                                     153
>   7643 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl backpropagation                                     154
>    231 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl clear                                               130
>     20 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl clear                                               131
>      8 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl clear                                               132
>    974 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl clear                                               133
>   2432 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl clear                                               135
>      1 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl evaluate                                             90
>   2604 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl evaluate                                             92
>      2 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl evaluate                                             93
>     34 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl evaluate                                            101
>      1 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl evaluate                                            102
>      1 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl evaluate                                            106
>    532 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl propagateDerivatives                                141
>   1127 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl propagateDerivatives                                142
>      1 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl propagateDerivatives                                143
>   4887 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl propagateDerivatives                                144
>   8887 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl propagateDerivatives                                145
>     10 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl train                                               160
>      2 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl train                                               161
>   9031 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl train                                               163
>   1725 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl train                                               166
>     77 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl train                                               171
>     53 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl train                                               175
>      8 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl updateWeights                                       111
>     31 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl updateWeights                                       112
>      2 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl updateWeights                                       114
>    117 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl updateWeights                                       115
>      1 ...esktop/julia/neuralnetwork.jl updateWeights                                       116
>  10932 REPL.jl                          eval_user_input                                      54
>      1 REPL.jl                          eval_user_input                                      55
>      1 array.jl                         -                                                   719
>      1 array.jl                         getindex                                            271
>  10932 profile.jl                       anonymous                                            14
>      1 random.jl                        RandIntGen                                          179
>      7 reduce.jl                        _mapreduce                                          168
>      7 reduce.jl                        mapreduce_pairwise_impl                             125
>      1 reduce.jl                        mapreduce_seq_impl                                  210
>      2 reduce.jl                        mapreduce_seq_impl                                  211
>      1 reduce.jl                        mapreduce_seq_impl                                  212
>      1 reduce.jl                        mapreduce_seq_impl                                  214
>      2 reduce.jl                        mapreduce_seq_impl                                  217
>      2 string.jl                        print                                                 4
>      8 string.jl                        println                                               5
>  10933 task.jl                          anonymous                                            96
> ```

Comment: noob question: why don't you use a some kind of Matricial calculation instead of introducicing new class ?

Comment: @Imorin, because it's much more readable and elegant in this form, but you're right the efficient way is to vectorize it (or with Julia use nested loops).  My hope was that Julia would be fast enough that I wouldn't have to write it in a different form, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It is neither efficient nor readable to implement neural nets without matrix operations.

Comment: It should be efficient in Julia using nested loops, but apparently not using a network class structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright so I've done a lot of experimenting and the problem seems to be accessing data internal to a type via another type.  Specifically accessing `d.source.activation` appears to be about 100 times more costly than just accessing `d.augmented`.  If you replace `d.source.activation` with `1.0` you'll more than double the speed.

It's also possible this is because the type info provided to the compiler concerning `source` is an abstract type `AbstractNode`, rather than a concrete type.  But I know of no way around this.

Either way this is as far as I can tell a serious performance issue which I don't immediately see how to circumvent.

However the other two suspicious lines, upon closer consideration, seem actually to be about right, so it's just line 144 which was causing the slow down.

Moreover by getting rid of the syntactic sugar `+=` in line 144, one can shave about 10 percent off the time, so there is an issue with that as well.

Answer (score 2):

This change is predicated on the assumption that your program is currently giving you the correct output. If a `BiasNode` or `InputNode` is passed into either `clear(...)` or `propDer(...)` these functions will crash because they each access `activationPrime`, a field which is unique to `type Node`. If we change the parameter type of `obj` in each of these functions to `Node` we should see some speed-up in the execution of your program. The reason why is because we are no longer passing a parameter with a type that has arbitrary size with arbitrary fields (`AbstractNode`), instead we are passing a parameter with a type that has explicit size and explicit fields (`Node`). Also in `clear(...)` I moved the access and modification of `obj`'s fields outside of the for loop, as they should only need to be modified once.

```
    function clear(obj::Node)
        obj.activation = -1.0
        obj.activationPrime = -1.0
        for d in obj.incomingEdges
            # loop body
        end
    end

    function propagateDerivatives(obj::Node, error::Float64)
        # function body
    end
```

Comment: But then these functions could not accept `InputNode` or `BiasNode`.

Comment: Neither `InputNode` nor `BiasNode` have any incoming edges, thus the functions never attempt to access obj.activationPrime in their case.